# How to use enums in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, enums

How do you use enums in Oracle using SQL only? (No PSQL)

In MySQL you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
   name ENUM('small', 'medium', 'large')
);
```

What would be a similar way to do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Reading a bit about the [MySQL enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html), I'm guessing the closest equivalent would be a simple check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
  name VARCHAR2(10) CHECK( name IN ('small','medium','large') )
);
```

but that doesn't allow you to reference the value by the index.  A more complicated foreign key relationship would also be possible

```
CREATE TABLE valid_names (
  name_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name_str  VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO valid_sizes VALUES( 1, 'small' );
INSERT INTO valid_sizes VALUES( 2, 'medium' );
INSERT INTO valid_sizes VALUES( 3, 'large' );

CREATE TABLE sizes (
  name_id NUMBER REFERENCES valid_names( name_id )
);

CREATE VIEW vw_sizes
  AS 
  SELECT a.name_id name, <<other columns from the sizes table>>
    FROM valid_sizes a,
         sizes       b
   WHERE a.name_id = b.name_id
```

As long as you operate through the view, it would seem that your could replicate the functionality reasonably well.

Now, if you admit PL/SQL solutions, you can create custom object types that could include logic to limit the set of values they can hold and to have methods to get the IDs and to get the values, etc.

Comment: You do have Enums in MySQL, they're quite helpful :)  Thanks anyways!

Comment: Not sure this is any closer, but I figured I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Yes that is closer, and its also the solution I'm currently using, but just wished there was a better way

Comment: Unfortunately I need to support 3 different databases, so I can't use PL/SQL or stick with only MySQL's nice feature.

Comment: Although it's not exactly the ideal solution, short of oracle adding new features, this is the only way to do (circa 2008).

Comment: Now almost three years later - is this still the recommended practice with the latest and greatest Oracle 11g ?

Comment: @User272735 - Yes, this is still the appropriate way to model this sort of constraint in 11.2.

Comment: @JustinCave Is it possible to have a set of constants from a package in the valid values list?

Comment: @ChetterHummin - I don't believe so, no.  You could have the package create a collection of the valid values on initialization by reading the data from the lookup table.

Comment: @JustinCave now after 14 years, is it still the closest way to apply Enums in PL-SQL. By not able to reference value by index did you mean we cannot use where clause with this column while using the constraint approach.

Comment: @Sandeep - I believe so, yes.  By "referencing the value by index" I mean the ability in MySQL to frequently substitute the enum's index for its string value.  You can certainly use a `where` clause to query a table with a constraint on it.  In the case where you created the foreign key to a lookup table, you'd need to join to the lookup table if you wanted the predicate to be on the string value or use the numeric key value in a predicate against the base table.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a constraint for the column? It will do the same thing:

ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT size_constraint check (x_size in ('small', 'medium', 'large'))

Comment: Will I be able to reference value by index?

Answer (score 1):

At this link you can find an alternative solution/workaround for Oracle, inspired by C language enums: http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001246.htm

Shortly put, Pete suggests to define some integer constants and to use a SUBTYPE to constrait them:

```sql
RED constant number(1):=1;
GREEN constant number(1):=2;
BLUE constant number(1):=3;
YELLOW constant number(1):=4;

subtype COLORS is binary_integer range 1..4;
```

After that you can declare variables, pass parameters and return values from functions and so on, with type COLORS.

Comment: that is explicitly for PL/SQL (it's in the article title), and the OP specifically said that he needed SQL and not PL/SQL. The comments on Justin's answer also mention that is has to be work in multiple databases and can't use Oracle-specific features.

Comment: As a dev that started with MySQL and moved to Oracle, everyday I find myself astounded that the enterprise product lacks the feature set of the free database product. I wonder if there is a clear performance justification for why such types are not available in MSSQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: @JosephLust What's the difference between MySQL enum and Oracle having a varchar2 with check constraint? They seem, practically speaking, to be the same thing, with the additional benefit that it's not a new data type. The long list of column data types is fairly ridiculous in MySQL - having so many has to have a cost, at least a maintenance cost.

Comment: @fool4jesus Main difference is storage requirement + also index size. ENUM allows you to store 255 arbitrary named values in 1 byte. With varchar2 you need X bytes for each row based on the name. (Or instead use separate lookup table with VIEW or JOINs to see the names as mentioned in first answer).

Comment: @JosephLust kind of OT explanation would be that expensive products are not (necessarily) of better quality, but only better sold or marketed.