# How do i add a column in oracle with Enum values?

Tags: sql, oracle, enums

[How to use enums in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203469/how-to-use-enums-in-oracle)

The above post gives me an option to create a Enum column while creating a table. But I have a table that is having values. I wanted to add another column with Enum values.

```
ALTER TABLE CARS **(ADD** BODY_TYPE VARCHAR2(20) 
                    CHECK (BODY_TYPE IN ('COUPE','SEDAN','SUV')) );
```

I'am getting a syntax error near `ADD`. Please guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place "add" before "(".

```
alter table cars
add
(
  body_type varchar2(20) not null check (body_type in ('COUPE','SEDAN','SUV'))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomasz, The syntax worked. One another concern, this created the column as null able.  Though this is a enum column the column shouldnt allow null right ?

Comment: If you want to constrain the column body_type that you are creating right now (which follows from the edited query in your question), then the only problem with that query was "add" in a wrong place. If you don't want to allow null values in the column, just put "not null" constraint besides the "check" one. I have edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: @Jeslinedias: to add a `NOT NULL` column you need also include a default value if there are already rows in the table. E.g. ` add body_type varchar2(20)  default 'SEDAN' ....`