# Best datatype for column indicating the enumerated type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, database-schema

I need to add column to a table, which represent the origin of value in another column. I.e. it's an enumerated value of known origins.

What is the best datatype to represent the value? Should I use an integer or string? I realize best design would store both columns in another table, but it's not possible at the moment.

Also, would it be better to represent unknown origin with some fixed value or null?

Comment: Seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203469/how-to-use-enums-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

> "I realize best design would store both columns in another table, but it's not possible at the moment."

If you cannot create a lookup table then you need to store the meaning. So choose the data type which fits the meaning. That is, if your enumeration is 'Red, Amber, Green' go for `varchar2(5)`. Use a check constraint to restrict it to valid input.

If you use integer you need to store the translation somewhere else. The meaning of data must reside in the database.

Obviously you need to duplicate the list of values in whatever UI populates the column. This is the technical debt incurred for not creating a lookup table.

> "would it be better to represent unknown origin with some fixed value or null?"

The best option would be to have an explicit value of `'unknown'` or whatever fits. The next best option is null: nulls are messy and can make queries harder to write, but magic values are worse because they work like real data and so can lead to misleading results.