# Cannot create table with enum field in it (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, enums, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a table which contains an enum in Oracle 11g

```
CREATE TABLE role (name ENUM('admin', 'read', 'write', 'manager'));
```

I'm getting `[42000][907] ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Position: 28`. Position 28 is between `ENUM` and `(`.

The example listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/enum.html) with the `shirts` table doesn't work either.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you are referring to is for MySQL, not the Oracle database. So your statement will probably work on the MySQL database.

Comment: Hm, the result of my search was misleading then. Thanks for noticing that. So there's no `ENUM` keyword for oracle databases?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203469/how-to-use-enums-in-oracle), but it's fairly old.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this :

```
  CREATE TABLE role (

  name varchar(10) check(role in ('admin', 'read', 'write', 'manager')) 

  );
```